# Firebase - what is the minimal security rules for the tables in order to protect your data e.g. from unauthenticated users / hackers

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Firebase - what is the minimal security rules for the tables in order to protect your data e.g. from unauthenticated users / hackers

I am about to go live and currently have all my tables set to true for read and write.

Thank you.

Comment: Simple check if someone is authenticated: ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "auth != null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  "rules": {
          // Only authenticated user can read
          ".read": "auth != null",
          // Only authenticated user can write
          ".write": "auth != null",
     }
}
```